# Select outgoing mail folder in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

On my iPhone, I can go to **Settings > Mail > *Any Account* > Account > Advanced > Sent Mailbox** and select which folder I'd prefer to have my Sent mail stored in. How can I do this in Mail on a Mac? I am trying to change which folder the sent messages are stored in when saving them to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Mail** select the mailbox you want to use from the list on the left and navigate to the menu *Mailbox > Use this Mailbox For*, then choose the appropriate purpose from the menu:

[image: image of Use this Folder For menu]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue in the past.

You want to be sure to be using a single folder for Sent Mail across all devices and email clients. If you use webmail at all, there is a standard arrangement for inboxes and sent items. Christian [explains the issue well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19251/how-can-i-re-map-mails-sent-messages-folder-to-an-imap-servers-sent-mail-f?rq=1):

> I use Mail to connect to a traditional IMAP server (non-Gmail). I've noticed that all the messages I send are placed in Mail's "Sent" folder and that Mail is translating this folder to a server folder called "Sent Messages". The problem is that on the IMAP server, the real folder meant to store sent messages is called "Sent Mail".
>
> I occasionally send messages using the server's web interface. Because of this, over time I will have my sent messages spread out over "Sent Messages" and "Sent Mail" in the server. If I want to find a sent message, and because these messages are not consolidated, I now have two places I need to search thru.

I would recommend you map Apple Mail's Sent to "Sent Mail" as used by your IMAP webmail client and do the same with your iPhone.

[image: Apple-Mail-mailbox-assignment-for-IMAP]

The same system applies to [Drafts, Trash and Junk](https://foliovision.com/2012/09/apple-imap-sent-mail-wrong-folder). Bonus tip: don't use IMAP for drafts as they [drafts will multiply across all your computers](https://foliovision.com/2011/01/apple-mail-multiple-draft-messages-in-imap), becoming unmanageable (up to 25 copies). Instead use a local folder on each of your computers. It's possible that the drafts multiplying like rabbits bug was fixed some time after Apple Mail 4.6 (OS X 10.6.8) but I have no confirmation of a fix.